# When should a single session instance be used for requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, aiohttp

From the `aiohttp` docs:

> [An `aiohttp.ClientSession`] encapsulates a connection pool (connector instance) and supports keepalives by default. **Unless you are connecting to a large, unknown number of different servers over the lifetime of your application, it is suggested you use a single session for the lifetime of your application to benefit from connection pooling.**

I have almost always used the practice of keeping a single `ClientSession` instance (with cookies enabled & a custom connector/adapter*) for any size or container of URLs, no matter how heterogeneous those URLs are or how many of them there are.  I would like to know if there are downsides to that approach.

I'm hoping to have a more granular, contextual definition of what "large, unknown number of different servers" constitutes in practice.  What are the best practices for cases like the one presented below?  Should a `ClientSession` be dedicated to each netloc, rather than a single instance for the whole set?**  Is the decision over whether to use a single client session dictated solely by response time?

It is often the case that I have "batches" of endpoints; the netloc for each batch is homogenous, but the netlocs between batches are different.  For example,

```
urls = {
    'https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html',
    'https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client_reference.html',
    'https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web_advanced.html#aiohttp-web-middlewares',

    'https://www.thesaurus.com/',
    'https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/encapsulate',
    'https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/connection?s=t',

    'https://httpbin.org/',
    'https://httpbin.org/#/HTTP_Methods',
    'https://httpbin.org/status/200'
}
```

To put a number on it, in reality each batch is probably of length 25-50.

---

<sub>*What I have done now is to limit open connections to any single host by passing a connector instance to `ClientSession`, which is `aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit_per_host=10)`.</sub>

<sub>**Specifically, `{'www.thesaurus.com', 'aiohttp.readthedocs.io', 'httpbin.org'}` i.e. `set(urllib.parse.urlsplit(u).netloc for u in urls)`.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd want to use a dedicated session with it's own connector when

1. You want to customise the connector parameters for a set of connections (say, alter the limit per host, or alter the SSL configuration, or set different timeouts).
2. You'd run through the default 100 connections limit at which point cached connections to existing hosts are just as likely to have been recycled as to be open still.

The latter scenario is what the documentation hints at. Say you have a larger number of unique hosts to connect to (where a unique host is a unique combination of hostname, port number and whether or not SSL is used), but *some* of those hosts are being contacted more often than others. If that 'large number' is > 100, then chances are that you have to keep opening new connections for the 'frequent' hosts you already connected to before, because the pool had to close them to create a connection for a host not currently in the pool. That'll hurt performance.

But if you created a *separate* pool for the 'frequent' hosts, then you can keep those host connections open much longer. They don't have to compete for free connections from the 'general use' pool with all those infrequent host connections.

In aiohttp you create separate pools by using separate sessions, you'll have to then define logic to pick what session to use for a given request.

For comparison, the `requests` library (a synchronous HTTP API) handles this a little differently, where you can [register separate transport adapters per url prefix](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#transport-adapters).

Comment: Thank you.  To confirm my understanding--the `limit` argument for [`aiohttp.TCPConnector`](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client_reference.html#tcpconnector) (default 100) refers to the max number of open connections to a set of *hosts*, rather than individual/full URIs?

Comment: Secondly, your answer would suggest using a single session and manipulating (1) the `limit` and `limit_per_host` parameters to the `connector` and (2) the parameters to the session instance itself, rather than creating a separate session for each batch.  ("But if you created a separate pool for the 'frequent' hosts, then you can keep those host connections open much longer."--it seems the easier route would be to simply increase connection limits on 1 session.)  Am I interpreting that correctly?

Comment: @BradSolomon: yes, the connection pool limit is there for the number of connections, which are per host. A request for `example.com/foo/bar` followed by `example.com/spam/ham` can reuse the open connection to `example.com` (provided another asyncio task is not still using it).

Comment: @BradSolomon: and no, manipulating `limit` and `limit_per_host` will not help in the scenario outlined. Say the [DMOZ project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMOZ) was still alive and you were trying to scrape it. You'd run a series of tasks to connect to DMOZ, retrieve URLs for other sites, and then scrape those other sites. That's a lot of URLs, and you would not want to lose connections to DMOZ. A limit_per_host would cap DMOZ connections, connections to a huge number of other domains would never hit limit_per_host. A bunch of slow external URLs would use up the `limit` pool, however

Comment: what if I have 50 urls and each of them is different? Do i need a session object for all 50 of them or do I need one session object per url? frequency would be to load them every minute

Comment: @PirateApp: use one session object, it'll handle connection reuse if some of your URLs end up on the same server, and otherwise will give you new connections when your URLs go to entirely different servers. The default is to handle 100 unique connections, with 50 URLs you'll never hit that limit.

Comment: Thank you @MartijnPieters what happens when you cross a 100? Does the program crash?

Comment: @PirateApp: please read my answer carefully. No, it won't crash, but cached, open connections will be closed to make room for a new connection.